# How to restrict apache virtual hosts?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have one site enabled, for example `foobar.com`.
But when I open IP address 127.0.0.1 - it's opens my `foobar.com`.
Whatever maps to 127.0.0.1 in `/etc/hosts` I open - `foobar.com` is opened.

How can I configure virtualhost/apache to only allow access from `foobar.com`?

Apache 2.4, Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache always uses the first VirtualHost as the "default" host. That is, whenever it can't map the requested hostname (`127.0.0.1` in your case) to a specific VirtualHost, it will use that default one.

Just define another VirtualHost before the `foobar.com` one. If you have both in the same configuration, configure the default one first. If you have separate config files, name the "default" one so, that it gets loaded before the `foobar.com` one. Many Linux distributions use a name like `00-default.conf` for the default VHost.

Comment: Thanks you. I totally forgot about this.